# bufferGeometry setFromPoints with react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Considering `toLinePath` function:

```
const toLinePath = (arrayOfPoints, color = 0x000000) => {
  const path = new THREE.Path();
  const firstPoint = arrayOfPoints[0];

  path.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y, firstPoint.z);
  arrayOfPoints.forEach(point => path.lineTo(point.x, point.y, point.z));
  path.closePath();

  const points = path.getPoints();
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
  const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color });
  const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  return line;
};
```

I want to recreate it using [`react-three-fiber`](https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber/tree/f0dc52e3ed777aa8172d68e37104c6b0ea0599dd) and been trying something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Canvas } from 'react-three-fiber'

function LinePath(props) {
  const vertices = React.useMemo(() => {
    const path = new THREE.Path()
    const firstPoint = props.vertices[0]

    path.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y, firstPoint.z)
    props.vertices.forEach(point => path.lineTo(point.x, point.y, point.z))
    path.closePath()

    return path.getPoints()
  }, [props.vertices])

  return (
    <line>
      <bufferGeometry attach="geometry" setFromPoints={vertices} />
      <lineBasicMaterial attach="material" color="black" />
    </line>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Canvas>
    <LinePath vertices={[new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(2, 2, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-2, 2, 0)]} />
  </Canvas>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

But there's no output/error at all. I suppose I've completely misunderstood `react-three-fiber`s API. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks and here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-react-spring-jqoyj)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For a future googler, useUpdate has been removed here:

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/pull/996.

**Use** **useLayoutEffect** instead.

```
 const ref = React.useRef<BufferGeometry>(null!);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.setFromPoints(points);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <line>
      <bufferGeometry attach='geometry' ref={ref} />
      <lineBasicMaterial color={0xff0000} />
    </line> 
  );
```

Answer (score 8):

So I actually figured it out. What I was looking for is [`useUpdate`](https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber#useupdatecallback-dependencies-optionalrefundefined) hook which allows us to invoke methods of any given `ref`. So that's what needs to be done:

```
import { Canvas, useUpdate } from 'react-three-fiber'

function LinePath(props) {
  const vertices = ...

  const ref = useUpdate(geometry => {
    geometry.setFromPoints(vertices)
  }, [])

  return (
    <line>
      <bufferGeometry attach="geometry" ref={ref} />
      ...
    </line>
  )
}
```

Comment: Not working for me for some reason. It does not enter the useUpdate callback function

Comment: can't tell a thing without some code. create a sandbox